# implement signature on mobile ReactJs

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, capacitor, signature

I have a ReactJs application which uses Capacitor to create the mobile version (android), my problem is that I want to implement a component to take the signature of the users, I have searched many libraries but at the time of generating the APK and trying to install it in Some devices give me an error "An error occurred during packet analysis."

Does anyone know of a library or solution to implement in my application?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is unclear; did you actually used some library and got the error? If yes, share the code so we can help you, instead of direct you for an entirely different pathway.